# FlowTypes how to import types from private npm module

Tags: javascript, npm, flowtype

I am writing private npm package to use internally, I also want to include some flowtypes in there that will be shared between internal projects and imported in following format `import type {SomeType} from 'our-private-lib'` But I am having trouble in doing so, what is the best approach to include flow types with npm package?

Currently I am transpiling all ES code with babel and then also using `flow-copy-source` to copy original files over along side transpiled files but with `.js.flow` extension, but then that means that the name of these files should be the same as the transpiled file?

For example if I have file in `/super-schema/index.js` with

```
export type SuperSchemaType = {
 prop1: boolean,
 prop2: string
}

const SuperSchema = {
 prop1: true,
 prop2: 'Hello'
}

module.exports = SuperSchema;
```

And package.json points to main file `index.js` which exports `SuperSchema` like so

```
module.exports = {
  superSchema: require('./super-schema.js/index.js');
}
```

I then can import that like so

`import {superSchema} from 'our-private-lib';`

but what about flowtype? `import type { SuperSchemaType } from 'our-private-lib';` Doesn't really work

Comment: Seems to be related discussion here https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/1996

Comment: Touch up me if I\`ll make a mistake. You have some lib with flow typing. You transpile it with babel and lost flow and workaround with restoring the flow doesn\`t work?
Have you ability do transpiling with major project only (that uses the lib)?

Comment: @KirillGlazunov flowtypes works in my lib, what I really want to do is to import flowtypes from that lib to use elsewhere in other projects like so `import type {SomeType} from 'our-private-lib'`

Comment: Do you transpiling your lib alone or as a part of a project that uses it (with project together)?

Comment: I am transpiling it alone before shipping, but also i ship non-transpiled es6 modules also and es6 preserved files with all flowtypes with `.js.flow` prepended to them, so there's different versions of same files available for different uses (node commonjs, es6, etc)

Comment: package.json is set to use `lib/index.js` as main entry point, it is auto generated to export all other util files, but obviously there are no flow type exports there, there's also `lib/index.js.flow` but it also doesn't have flow type exports, it would be very inconvenient to keep all flow type exports in one file `index.js.flow`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your general approach is correct (using flow-copy-source), but if you want to consume types out of the main entry point of your module, you need to export the types out one way or another. You can do that explicitly by doing something like

```
export type {
  SuperSchemaType
} from './super-schema';
```

Or, if you're using babel 7, export type * might be useful for you

```
export type * from './super-schema';
```

Comment: Thank you, my problem was that i was trying to mix normal js exports and flowtypes somehow together, as soon as i started treating them separately it all worked fine